# Minecraft Open Command is not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I moved Minecraft Java 1.16.2 to my Windows 10 PC.  Everything is working fine with the exception that the Open Command "/" is not working.  I changed the "/" to a different character, but it still did not work.  I moved the keyboard back to my Windows 7 laptop, and it worked fine.  Help please, I do not know what else to try.

Comment: Does `t` (open chat) work? You can type commands that way too, you just need to type the `/` yourself, it doesn't enter it for you. Also can you type `/` in anything other than Minecraft? My suspicion is a national keyboard mapping where the `/` key produces a completely different character.

Comment: @SF. that would make sense, except he says even when he rebinds the key to something else it does not work, also he seems to be able to type it in this question, so the character is still slash `/`